# Encode many objects to json

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-php-sdk, json

I want to encode some facebook data in a json, but if I do, for example

```
$likes = idx($facebook->api('/me/likes?limit=5000'), 'data', array());
fwrite($fileout,json_encode($likes));
$friends = idx($facebook->api('/me/friends?limit=5000'), 'data', array());
fwrite($fileout,json_encode($friends));
```

Now the problem with that is that it will produce a invalid json. They will both produce an entire json, with '[' and ']', however a valid json should **only** have **one** of each bracket in the entire file

Can you please advise me how should I deal with this?

Comment: Put both data structures into one array/object first, and then encode that as JSON afterwards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$likes = idx($facebook->api('/me/likes?limit=5000'), 'data', array());
$friends = idx($facebook->api('/me/friends?limit=5000'), 'data', array());

$array = array($likes, $friends);

fwrite($fileout,json_encode($array));
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$var[1]= idx($facebook->api('/me/likes?limit=5000'), 'data', array());
$var[2] = idx($facebook->api('/me/friends?limit=5000'), 'data', array());

fwrite($fileout,json_encode($var));
```